# Lebesgue- integrability of powers 2 and 3 of a function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ , and $f^2$ is L-integrable, is $f$ also L-integrable? What if $f^3$ is L-integrable?

Comment: this is a trick question.   you may have $f^2$ integrable but $f$ not measurable.

Comment: I'm considering measurable functions.

Comment: But if $f$ is measurable, you have $f$ integrable since $|f| \le 1 + |f|^p$ for any $p\ge 1$.

Comment: @martini But what can we say for $p<1$ ?

Comment: Then $f$ needn't be integrable, for example is $x^{-1}$ integrable over $[0,1]$, but its square root (i. e. $p = 1/2$) $x^{-1/2}$ is ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a non-measurable subset of $[0,1]$ then
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }x\in A \\ -1 & \text{if }x\not\in A \end{cases}
$$
is not measurable, but its square is Lebesgue-integrable.

However, if $f$ is measurable, then integrability of $f^2$ does imply that of $f$.  To show this you need to rely on the fact that the measure of the domain is finite.  You have
$$
\int_{[0,1]} |f| \le \int\left.\begin{cases} |f| & \text{on }\{|f|\le 1\} \\  f^2 & \text{on } \{f>1\} \end{cases}\right\} \le 1 + \int |f|^2.
$$

Comment: This uses less background than my answer (+1). However, I would have compared $|f|$ to $1$ on $\{|f|\le1\}$ instead of $|f|$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $x^2$ is a convex function and $[0,1]$ has measure $1$, [Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) says that
$$
\left(\int_0^1|f|\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^2\le\int_0^1|f|^2\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
Furthermore, [Cauchy-Schwarz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality) says
$$
\int_0^1|f|\cdot1\,\mathrm{d}x\le\left(\int_0^1|f|^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}\left(\int_0^11^2\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/2}
$$

---

**For any $p\ge1$**

Since $x^p$ is a convex function and $[0,1]$ has measure $1$, [Jensen's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) says that
$$
\left(\int_0^1|f|\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^p\le\int_0^1|f|^p\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
However, we need to use [Hölder's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality) instead of Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$
\int_0^1|f|\cdot1\,\mathrm{d}x\le\left(\int_0^1|f|^p\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/p}\left(\int_0^11^q\,\mathrm{d}x\right)^{1/q}
$$
where $\dfrac1p+\dfrac1q=1$.